# How to get scroll bar width of a QScrollArea in PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

For a `QScrollArea` `scroll` I want to dynamically get the width of its vertical scroll bar (or the height of its horizontal one).

- `scroll.verticalScrollBar().width())` seems to return a large number for it to be the width I am looking for, as I expect it to be around 15 px.

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: The size of widget is unreliable until they're shown the first time, but it's normally enough to get the `sizeHint()` for such situations. The question is, if you need it dynamically, it means that it should load whenever a resize or painting happens (so, it should be valid at that point), so may I ask what do you need that for?

Comment: @musicamante First of all, I need it because I need to find the exact dimensions of the visible area of the widget inside ```QScrollArea```, which would be the ```QScrollArea.width()``` - ```scroll bar width```. If I don't do so when the horizontal bar appears, I paint a slightly bigger picture than the one that scroll can hold, causing it to create a vertical scroll for these ~15 px. Second, ```sizeHint()```, returns a size of ```(52, 17)```. Does this mean that the width is 52? That seems odd to me! Also the height should be greater than 100-200 px.

Comment: Size management is difficult, especially if trying to adapt widgets and contents when they're shown the first time, and even more complex when dealing with scroll areas. That said, your question is a bit confusing: are you sure that you don't mean the *width* of the *vertical* scroll bar and *height* of the horizontal one? The one in the screenshot is the vertical one. If the size of your previous comment is the horizontal bar hint, it's correct: at that point you probably haven't set the widget for the scroll area, so 52 is the minimum width for the horizontal scroll bar, 17 its height.

Comment: What you need is to get the size hint for the *vertical* scroll bar, but you should also consider that QScrollArea inherits from QFrame, and the QStyle may add borders: in order to get the actual available width you must also add the scroll area `frameWidth()*2` (left+right borders). Then again, the problem still remains: due to its nature, a scroll area is resizable, so it is important to understand *when* you need to compute these sizes and for what, as depending on the situation *very* different solutions may apply. Can you [edit] your question and add more details about what you're doing?

Comment: @musicamante Thanks a lot! You have answered my question, since my confusion was indeed in the names horizontal and vertical. I _will_ be updating on every window resize so, yes, I will be taking care of everything that is needed.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that if the scroll area is resized and the widget is already set, you should verify *if* the scroll bar should be visible, but that might not happen immediately. If you're just showing a single image in a QLabel, you might want to use a subclass and use `setFixedHeight()` in the `resizeEvent()` using the original pixmap aspect ratio; note that: 1. you must set `setScaledContents(True)`; 2. set an `Ignored` size policy for both width and height; 3. set a simple flag *before* `setFixedHeight()` and unset it to avoid excessive recursion. Also consider using QGraphicsView.